GeoServer WFS Transaction is giving different result that the body
I'm trying to add new entry in my layer using WFS Transaction. my request is working fine and I'm getting 200 OK when executing. my body looks like
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"  xmlns:LMSRND="LMSRND" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"> 
    <wfs:Insert> 
        <LMSRND:cg_redline_info> 
            <LMSRND:shape> 
                <gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326" srsDimension="2"> 
                    <gml:exterior> 
                        <gml:LinearRing> 
                            <gml:coordinates>
                                73.77654680066294,18.65899103602948 73.77654680066294,18.65899103602948 73.77640381458797,18.65899103602948 73.77630372440093,18.658976738959403 73.7762465294473,18.658933847094694 73.77614643926029,18.658905252300062 73.77604634907325,18.658862360435354 73.7759748557085,18.6588337662952 73.77590336234374,18.658776576705936 73.77583186963352,18.658733684841227 73.77577467467991,18.658705090701073 73.77573177879196,18.65867649590644 73.77570318196969,18.65864790111181 73.77566028608175,18.658590712177023 73.77560309112812,18.658547820312315 73.77557449430584,18.658490631377532 73.77554589682904,18.658447739512823 73.77550300094109,18.658404847648114 73.77548870252996,18.65834765805885 73.77547440346429,18.658304766194142 73.77544580664201,18.65823328018928 73.77543150757634,18.658176090600016 73.77540291075407,18.658104604595152 73.77537431327725,18.65800452314118 73.77537431327725,18.657918739411762 73.77534571580044,18.657818658612268 73.77534571580044,18.65773287488285 73.77534571580044,18.657647091153432 73.77536001486612,18.657561307424015 73.77536001486612,18.657489820764674 73.77538861168838,18.657404037035256 73.77543150757634,18.657332551030397 73.77546010505314,18.657261064371056 73.77554589682904,18.65717528064164 73.77564598701606,18.657103793982298 73.77580327215672,18.656989416112726 73.77598915411964,18.656846442794045 73.7761750367371,18.656760659064627 73.77634662028888,18.656660578265132 73.7765325022518,18.656574794535715 73.7767326832804,18.656531902671006 73.77688996776651,18.656489010806297 73.77706155131828,18.656446118941588 73.77723313487007,18.656446118941588 73.7773618225339,18.656417524146956 73.77750480926342,18.656417524146956 73.77761919786158,18.65643182187151 73.77777648365678,18.656446118941588 73.77789087225494,18.656489010806297 73.77804815674105,18.656531902671006 73.77819114347056,18.656574794535715 73.77834842795667,18.656646281195055 73.77850571375185,18.656689173059764 73.77862010235002,18.65671776719992 73.77874879001386,18.65678925385926 73.77884888085543,18.656846442794045 73.77894897038792,18.656889334658754 73.77904906122949,18.656946524248017 73.77914915207106,18.657032307977435 73.77923494384694,18.657103793982298 73.77930643655716,18.65720387543627 73.77939222833305,18.657289659165688 73.77947802010894,18.65738973996518 73.77953521506257,18.657489820764674 73.77956381188484,18.657589902218646 73.7795924087071,18.657675685948064 73.77960670777279,18.657747171952927 73.77960670777279,18.657861550476976 73.77960670777279,18.65796163127647 73.77957811095051,18.65804741500589 73.77953521506257,18.658176090600016 73.77947802010894,18.658276172053988 73.77942082515533,18.658376252853483 73.77933503337943,18.658533523242237 73.77924924160354,18.658633604041732 73.77916344982765,18.658733684841227 73.77906336029515,18.6588337662952 73.77893467263132,18.658919550024617 73.77880598496748,18.659005333754035 73.77867729730364,18.659091117483452 73.7785486096398,18.65917690121287 73.77841992197597,18.65921979307758 73.7783198311344,18.659262684942288 73.77824833842418,18.659305576806997 73.77820544253623,18.65933417094715 73.77816254664829,18.659348468671705 73.77810535169466,18.659362765741783 73.7780767548724,18.65937706281186 73.7780767548724,18.65937706281186 73.77803385898446,18.659391360536414 73.77803385898446,18.659391360536414 73.7780052608531,18.65941995467657 73.7780052608531,18.65941995467657 73.77797666403083,18.65941995467657 73.77797666403083,18.65941995467657 73.77794806720856,18.65941995467657 73.77794806720856,18.65941995467657 73.77790517132061,18.65941995467657 73.77790517132061,18.65941995467657 73.77787657318926,18.65941995467657 73.77787657318926,18.65941995467657 73.777847976367,18.65940565760649 73.777847976367,18.65940565760649 73.77783367730132,18.65937706281186 73.77781937954472,18.659348468671705 73.77654680066294,18.65899103602948
                            </gml:coordinates>               
                        </gml:LinearRing> 
                    </gml:exterior> 
                </gml:Polygon> 
            </LMSRND:shape> 
            <LMSRND:remarks>test22</LMSRND:remarks> 
            <LMSRND:rname>Test 2</LMSRND:rname>     
        </LMSRND:cg_redline_info> 
    </wfs:Insert> 
</wfs:Transaction>

It is also getting stored correctly in DB.

But for some reason when I look for this feature on GeoServer, the coordinates are incorrect 

are you sure the coordinate order is right? It should be lat,lon

Tried with reversing coordinates as well, no luck though

I also checked geometry that is getting stored in db , that is also correct

Please add some details about where you are storing it and what it looks like there. Then try requesting it as GML rather than GeoJSON and see if that is right

Is cg_redline_info.81 certainly the same feature that you inserted? Can there be other features having remarks='test22'?

Yup, tried that as well , I'm having only 1 feature with remarks='test22'
